# Subroutine error calculating factorial: Useless use of private variable in void context

Tags: perl

I just started to learn Perl and have troubles to calculating factorials iteratively.

With this code I get the error:

> Useless use of private variable in void context

```
sub factorial {
    my ($input) = @_; #assigning argument

    for ( $input; $input > 0; $input -= 1 ) {
        my $factorial = $input * ($input -1);
        return $factorial;
    }
}
```

Has anybody an idea what went wrong there?

Comment: You return too early and can multiply by zero if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (A; B; C) { ... }
```

is basically

```
A;
while (B) { ... } continue { C }
```

so you are evaluating the following:

```
$input;
```

That has no effect, so Perl warns you that you probably didn't mean to do that!

---

Your loop makes no sense! You always return the first pass through. Worse, you don't return anything meaningful when `$input` is zero!

```
sub factorial {
    my ($n) = @_;
    my $accumulator = 1;
    for (; $n>0; --$n) {
       $accumulator *= $n;
    }

    return $accumulator;
}
```

There's rarely any reason to a C-style loop in Perl. The following is clearer:

```
sub factorial {
    my ($n) = @_;
    my $accumulator = 1;
    for my $i (2..$n) {
       $accumulator *= $i;
    }

    return $accumulator;
}
```

or

```
sub factorial {
    my ($n) = @_;
    my $accumulator = 1;
    $accumulator *= $_ for 2..$n;
    return $accumulator;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable (statement) `$input` in `for ($input; ...)` serves no purpose and does nothing. By adding `use diagnostics;` to the top of the program you'll get

> Useless use of private variable in void context at t.pl line 19 (#1)
>       (W void) You did something without a side effect in a context that does
>       nothing with the return value, [...]

You can also see this and directly fix it by

```
for (my $input = shift; $input > 0; $input -= 1) {
```

or

```
my ($input) = @_;
for (; $input > 0; $input -= 1) { ...
```

but then the rest is incorrect since `$factorial` is declared anew at every interation, and you return right away. So move the declaration part (`my $factorial;`) to before the loop and move `return` to after the loop. Then your code works -- other than for `0`, for which factorial need be `1`.

There are other ways, for example

```
sub factorial {
    my ($input) = @_;
    my $factorial = $input || 1              # 0! == 1
    $factorial *= $input while --$input > 1;
    return $factorial;
}
```

or the "standard" recursive way

```
sub factorial {
  my ($input) = @_;
  return 1 if $input == 0;
  return factorial($input-1) * $input;
}
```